# java.net.MalformedURLException for applet url

Tags: java, applet

I have signed my applet and it is in jar.

I have added the below code in my jsp to embedd applet

```
 <applet name="viewerApplet" id="TViewerApplet" width="100%" height="500" code="TViewerApplet.class" codebase="/WEB-INF/lib" mayscript="mayscript" archive="C:/Eclipse_Workspace/Velocity/BSLI_MIS_VELOCITY/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/SSignedTAppletViewer.jar">
```

but I get below exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
```

Edit:
Now I am using

```
<applet name="viewerApplet" id="TViewerApplet" width="100%" height="500" code="TViewerApplet.class" align="baseline" codebase="." mayscript="mayscript" archive="SSignedTAppletViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar">
```

New Exception
load: class TViewerApplet.class not found.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TViewerApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://10.160.118.171:8086/BSLI_MIS_VELOCITY/TViewerApplet/class.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TViewerApplet.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
archive="C:/Eclipse_Workspace/Velocity/BSLI_MIS_VELOCITY/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/SSignedTAppletViewer.jar"
```

There are two problems with this.

1. The archive attribute is a path relative (an HREF) to the codebase, whereas that points to a file path (as opposed to a `file:` based URL - hence `unknown protocol: c`).  But use a relative path.
2. `/WEB-INF/lib/` is typically reserved for the server and has no public access.  You need to put the Jar somewhere else.  I generally use `/lib/`.

### Update

> 1. TViewerApplet is in SSignedTAppletViewer.jar
> 2. Yes its is in package com.mind
> 3. Now jar is in same folder where jsp resides
> 4. I have checked with jar -tvf ,class is in the jar

Good.  Putting that all together results in an applet element like this:

```
<applet
    name="viewerApplet"
    id="TViewerApplet"
    width="100%"
    height="500"
    code="com.mind.TViewerApplet"
    align="baseline"
    codebase="."
    mayscript="mayscript"
    archive="SSignedTAppletViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar">
</applet>
```

The only change is in the `code` attribute, from `TViewerApplet.class` to `com.mind.TViewerApplet` - the `.class` is not necessary, but the package is.

Comment: thnks for the reply,I followed what you said <applet name="viewerApplet" id="TViewerApplet" width="100%" height="500" code="com.mindcraft.mis.boe.applet.TViewerApplet.class" align="baseline" codebase="C:/Documents and Settings/inos002827/Desktop/" mayscript="mayscript" archive="SSignedTAppletViewer.jar,cmbview81.jar">.Now I dont get error but the web page remains blank.

Comment: 1) Please edit HTML into the question, use code formatting, and notify me of the edit in a comment. 2) The `codebase` has be an URL or HREF as well.  But stop, *stop,* ***stop*** thinking about file paths or paths to the local disks.  Put the HTML and Jar in the **same directory** and specify codebase as `"."` (that is the default, but we'll be explicit).  I am not necessarily suggesting it should be deployed that way, but 1st let us see it working.

Comment: Which Jar is `TViewerApplet` in?  Is it in a package?  What path is it in the Jar?  Have you checked it is actually in the Jar (try `jar -tvf ..`)?

Comment: You answered 2 out of 4 of the questions I asked.  Want to take a crack at answering the other 2?

Comment: 1) TViewerApplet is in SSignedTAppletViewer.jar 2)Yes its is in package com.mind 3)Now jar is in same folder where jsp resides 4)I have checked with jar -tvf ,class is in the jar